# Why double variable is not showing remainder after division in c?

Tags: c, division

There must be some egregious mistake I'm guilty of but I'm calculating the result of 2880 * 12 / 512 in C and even though I'm saving the result in a `double` variable it just doesn't save the remainder. According to Google and any other calculator 2880 * 12 / 512 = 67.5 however according to the program below it's 67.00. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double result;
    result = 2880 * 12 / 512;
    printf("result = %f\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling the file called test.c which contains the code as: `gcc test.c -o test -lm`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did your favorite tutorial not cover this?

Comment: `2880 * 12 / 512` is all integer. You probably want `2880.0 * 12.0 / 512.0`

Comment: OT: The code you show does not use anything from `math.h` and/or `libm`. Including/linking is not necessary.

Comment: @alk — and `<stdint.h>`, `<string.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` are also redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type cast your integer literal value. Like this.

```
result = (double)2880 * 12 / 512;
```

C11 standard:

> **6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**
>
> **6** When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any
>   fractional part discarded.<sup>88)</sup> If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression
>   `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal a.

Comment: Advanced corner concern: `(double) some_integer` forces a conversion to `double`.  Had _some_integer_ been a large 60-bit number, that conversion may incurred rounding.  By nudging to `double` math with `1.0*some_integer` instead of a cast, and when FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2, the conversion may proceed using `long double` math and form a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

`2880 * 12 / 512` is all an integer expression and evaluates to an integer. After the fact it is assigned to a double variable, but then the precision is lost. You need to cast to a double so it evaluates to a double.

```
result = (double)2880 * 12 / 512;
```

or alternatively append a decimal point to tell the compiler that it is a floating point number:

```
result = 2880. * 12 / 512;
```